# The "p" in Trump

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I used many online resources to find out how to correctly pronounce the ending /p/ in "Trump". Is it aspirated [pʰ] or is it just [p]?

Dictionaries don't answer this question because they include phonemic transcriptions, not phonetic, so they don't tell me which allophone to use.

Comment: Why do you think it's pronounced differently from [trump](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/trump) ?

Comment: @ColleenV♦: Perhaps because when you get right down to the nitty-gritty, ***trump*** and ***triumph*** are essentially "the same word" (they're certainly [cognate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cognate), in the sense of having the same etymological roots).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just think the question would be better if it explained why the dictionary entries for "trump" didn't help.

Comment: If you're referring to the current U.S. president, there are innumerable clips of him saying his own name (really, it's impossible to avoid them; I've tried). That is the best place to start when pronouncing anyone's name, as  spelling is only loosely tied to pronunciation in English.

Comment: @ravi Don't confuse the concept of "aspirated" phones (or sounds) with "released" phones. This Wikipedia page may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release.

Comment: @ColleenV I think that OP has some basic elementary knowledge of English phonemes and basically wants to know "Is the /p/ in /trʌmp/ aspirated. I don't understand exactly how a dictionary is going to help with that. Dictionaries only give phonemic information and do not say if a particular phoneme is going to be aspirated (or labialised or nasalised, or fronted, or backed, or palatalised or ejective). This seems to be a perfectly good question to me ...

Comment: @choster  Yes, but it's difficult to tell fine information like that from just listening to native speakers. Most native speakers will find it difficult to tell if a particular instance of a /p/ or other plosive is aspirated or not ...

Comment: @Araucaria Now that information has been added to the question, it's much better, don't you think? That's all I was getting at. I was also hoping that we could talk about trump instead of Trump.

Comment: @ColleenV Indeed, but I think it would be very difficult for an English learner to write the question that way! Completely agree about Trump/trump. Although it does provide click-bait.

Answer (score 5):

English /p/ will be strongly aspirated at the beginning of a stressed syllable, as in the words:

- **pot**, '**parr**ot, a'**ppear**

At the beginning of unstressed syllables, or at the end of a syllable, it will have only a very little aspiration. In other words we think of it as 'unaspirated':

- 'happy, po'tato

When /p/ occurs at the end of a word in English it may have no audible release:

- tap, shop, trump

When our lips come together to make the [p] in these words, the audible word will (usually) finish. We don't hear the lips coming apart again or the air from the [p] escaping.

Answer (score 3):

In English aspiration is entirely conditioned by the phonetic context. Only voiceless stops (/p/,/t/,/k/) are aspirated, and these are only aspirated when they occur **a)** alone (that is, not as part of a consonant cluster) **b** before a stressed vowel.

Neither of these requirements is met in the name of our new Grand Orange: the /p/ occurs in the consonant cluster /mp/, and it occurs at the end of the syllable. Consequently, it's not aspirated.

In fact, in many contexts—at the end of a sentence, or even when a following stressed syllable begins with a vowel (e.g. "Trump oughta [whatever you want him to do]), which should cause the /p/ to act as the syllable onset—the /p/ won't be discernibly 'pronounced' at all: the /m/ has already effected its defining lip closure, and the glottal closure which accompanies stops for many speakers is likely to completely mask its release. But that doesn't matter: the closure will signal to any listeners that there *should* be a /p/ there, and that's what they will 'hear'.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. It could have no audible release, or moderate aspiration. It would not be extremely strongly aspirated.

John Wells' phonetic blog, a very useful resource for information about English pronunciation, has the following relevant post: 
[VOT is more](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/vot-is-more.html)

Wells says the main positions where we consistently see no aspiration on English voiceless stops are immediately before other obstruents (stops or fricatives), or after tautosyllabic /s/. The main position we consistently see the strongest level of aspiration used in English is in the onset of a stressed syllable. In other contexts, the level of aspiration may vary depending on the accent, or even depending on the individual speaker or utterance.

Answer (score -3):

[It's simply "p".](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPejbMdQUs0) The link is a video showing how to pronounce it.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. There are many different ways of saying /p/.

Comment: There's a video.

Comment: Answers that are just links to other sites are discouraged. See: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/273494). Please explain the essential parts of the answer, and provide the link for reference. Most dictionaries provide a clip of how to pronounce a word, so how is this video superior to, for example, [the audio clip for trump in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trump)?

Comment: It's not superior in any way. Nor is writing out the correct pronunciation superior. The issue is that the question is unnecessary given how easy it is to find a clip of the pronunciation.